# Find all external links with Simple HTML Dom Parser and regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

How can I find all external links on a page using regular expressions and Simple HTML DOM Parser? I have the following code to find all links.

```
<?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url = "http://www.tokyobit.com";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
        echo $a;
    }
?>
```

How can I add a regular expression to find all links starting with `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://`?

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $regex = ; //regex here
    if(preg_match_all($regex, $a, $matches)){
        foreach($matches as $match){
            echo $match . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I think that trying to parse HTML with php puts you halfway on the road to writing an HTML parser. Do you have access to the DOM on Js?. It would be much easier to just write some ajax callbacks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the $regex variable to:

```
$regex = "#(https?|ftp)://.#";
```

Comment: You can make your regex simpler by using another enclosing character `~`  or `#` for instance. This would avoid escaping `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom strpos to use an array as a needle

You'll first need this function

```
function strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset=0) {
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
    foreach($needle as $query) {
        if(strpos($haystack, $query, $offset) !== false) return true; // stop on first    true result
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your code

```
$needle = array("ftp://","http://","https://");
foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    if(strposa($a, $needle){
        echo $matches;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    if(preg_match('#^(?:https?|ftp)://.+$#', $a->href)){
        echo $matches;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.tokyobit.com";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$result = array();

foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $href = $a->href;
    if (strpos($href, '://', 3)!==false) $result[] = $href;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: @pguardiario: the "3" is the third parameter and indicate the index where you start the search in the string. Since the smallest possible start of the string is `ftp` (index 0 to 2), the first position where you can find the `://` is "3" (no need to test the 3 first).

Comment: If you think about it though, anywhere that `://` appears is enough for a match.

Comment: @pguardiario: indeed, but don't forget that you are looking for an url inside an href attribute, this is not a random string.

Comment: I know that. I'm saying that, for example, '://foo.com' is a hyperlink and should also match.